# "You reduced me to tears", What does it mean?

Tags: meaning

It is from an old movie. I don't remember the title but this sentence is also used in 'Grace Kelly' of Mika.

Does it mean 'You made me cry'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, it means the person is pretty well devastated. Literally it means that the person is gone and nothing is left except his or her tears. Wow that is a very sad description.

Answer (score 1):

That's right.  It usually means more than just "you made me cry", it means your REALLY made me cry.